# Edit a Key/Value Parameters list Formset

Tags: django

I'm looking for a convenient solution to create an 'edit settings' key/values page.

Parameters model :

```
class Parameter(models.Model):
    key = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    showInUI = models.SmallIntegerField()
```

Initial Keys/Values are already inserted in table.
I load them and send them using a model formset factory using these lines :

```
ParameterFormSet = modelformset_factory(Parameter, extra=0, fields=('key', 'value'))
parameterFormSet = ParameterFormSet(queryset=Parameter.objects.filter(showInUI=1))
return render_to_response('config.html', {'parameterFormSet': parameterFormSet}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Template side, when formset is displayed, keys and values are shown as inputs.

I'd like to find a convenient way to display form keys as readonly labels and values as inputs. And, when submited, validate them according django standards.

I've read a lot of stuff, I guess the solution may be a custom widget, but I could find a reliable solution.

Thanks for reading.

EDIT :

Working solution

views.py

```
def config(request):
    ParameterFormSet = modelformset_factory(Parameter, extra=0, fields=('value',))
    if request.method == "POST":
        try:
            formset = ParameterFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)
        except ValidationError:
            formset = None
            return HttpResponse("ko")
        if formset.is_valid():
            formset.save()
            return HttpResponse("ok")
    #ParameterFormSet = modelformset_factory(Parameter, extra=0, fields=('value',))
    parameterFormSet = ParameterFormSet(queryset=Parameter.objects.filter(showInUI=1))
    return render_to_response('config.html', {'parameterFormSet': parameterFormSet}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

template

```
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ parameterFormSet.management_form }}
    {% for form in parameterFormSet %}
        <div>
        {{ form.instance.key }}
        {{ form }}
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not want the value to be editable, don't include it in `fields` when creating the form set.

```
ParameterFormSet = modelformset_factory(Parameter, extra=0, fields=('value',)) # don't forget the trailing comma after 'value' otherwise it's not a tuple!
```

In your template, you can then loop through the forms in the form set, and display the key at the same time.

```
{% for form in parameter_form_set %}
    {{ form.instance.key }}{# display the key related to this form #}
    {{ form }}{# display the form #}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks, easy to implement and working solution.
Edited my answer with working code.